# Warnings and Errors when trying to do anything with UFW - uncomplicated fire wall

Tags: firewall, ufw

Probably a total noob question related to user error, but
when running

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

it returns that I have the newest version installed, but then if I try to either reset

```
sudo ufw reset
```

or check the status

```
sudo ufw status
```

It returns these errors.

```
WARN: '/etc/ufw/applications.d' does not exist
ERROR: Couldn't stat '/etc/default/ufw'
```

There is no ufw directory in my etc folder and uwf is definitely NOT in my default directory. Am I missing a step where I need to move some stuff into the right places or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/ufw/applications.d` directory and `/etc/default/ufw` file would have been created when `ufw` was originally installed - it sounds like you manually deleted them at some point.

You can see what packages (aside from `ufw` itself) would have placed application profiles into the directory on your particular system using a `dpkg` search:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/ufw/applications.d
postfix, openssh-server, samba, cups-daemon, ufw: /etc/ufw/applications.d
```

and re-install them e.g.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ufw openssh-server
```

Comment: Yes, this worked!